# Confluent Elasticsearch sink connector Indexname manipulation

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm still new to kafka and am looking for a solution to the following problem:
With Kafka Connect SMT it is possible to manipulate part of a topic or its name. 
Is there a way to get a date from the data stream and build an index name from it? 
For example:

```
{"transmitdate": "2020-03-20T14: 00: 00"} -> index name: foo-2020-03-20
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So I found the answer myself. 
The MessageTimestampRouter from the connector package is ideal for the task.

Here is a link:

https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/messagetimestamprouter.html#messagetimestamprouter